# How to search in a TableView based on an Array with NSManagedObject Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search, core-data

I want to include a search bar in my tableview (which is within a VC). However I am unsure how to actually search an Array:

```
var allLocations = [NSManagedObject]()
```

Which contains many Location objects with a `name` attribute.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction

I have been following this guide:https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Search-Bar-Guide

and it has led me to this method:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            allLocationsFiltered = searchText.isEmpty ? allLocations : allLocations.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
                let dataString2 = dataString.name
                return dataString2.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
            })

            tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

however I get an error saying

```
Cannot convert value of type '(String) -> Bool' to expected argument type '(NSManagedObject) -> Bool'
```

Comment: Try using predicate.

Comment: What about updating the predicate used for the request which has given you the managed object array? The updated predicate could include the search criteria? Are you using NSFetchedResultsController?